# Move nested files to root directory in DOS

Tags: command-line, file, directory, dos, move

I have a directory structures like so:

```
C:\mydir\foo\a.zip
C:\mydir\foo\b.zip
C:\mydir\bar\c.zip
C:\mydir\baz\d.zip
```

I would like to move all files in C:\mydir\*\*.zip to C:\mydir so the output structure would be:

```
C:\mydir\a.zip
C:\mydir\b.zip
C:\mydir\c.zip
C:\mydir\d.zip
```

...with the superfluous empty folders potentially still present. How do I accomplish this using only the DOS command-line?

Comment: Here are a couple of flatten scripts... haven't tried them myself, but worth posting here if one works for you: http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=24778

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CD /D C:\mydir
FOR /f "delims=" %a IN ('DIR *.zip /s /b') DO MOVE "%a" .
```

It first changes the directory to `C:\mydir`. The `DIR` lists all zip-files in subdirectories with filenames only. The `FOR` makes sure each lines goes into the variable `%a`. `MOVE` basically moves each file found into the current directory, i.e. `C:\mydir`.